# Cython (default) include directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, include, cython, mpi4py

I am writing some cython code which uses the packages `mpi4py` and `cython_gsl`. From Python I can do `import mpi4py` and `import cython_gsl` without errors. I can also do `from cython_gsl cimport *` which cythonizes, compiles and runs correctly. If I do `from mpi4py cimport *` however, I get the error `'mpi4py.pxd' not found`. I can make it work if I supply the option `-I /path/to/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages` when invoking cython.

The `__init__.pxd` files (which I believe is what is used by `cimport`) for the two packages are located in

```
/path/to/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cython_gsl/__init__.pxd
/path/to/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/__init__.pxd
```

My question is this: How come that cython is able to find the `__init__.pxd` for `cython_gsl` without explicitly including any path, but not the `__init__.pxd` for `mpi4py`? Sure the one for `mpi4py` is located at a deeper path, but why does including the `site-packages` directory enable cython to find `site-packages/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/__init__.pxd` when it already is able to find `site-packages/cython_gsl/__init__.pxd`?

My hypothesis is that `cython_gsl` adds itself to the list of directories to include by cython when it is installed. How can I see a list of all directories included by default when invoking cython?

Comment: It may help to have an empty `__init__.py` in the directory as well since I think that's what Python uses to determine what is a package (although it actually loads the pyd file). I find this package stuff slightly confusing though...